# tcl spawn sftp not working

Tags: tcl, expect

I am trying to run a very simple tcl script

```
package require Expect
spawn sftp user@host
```

the error I get is

> The system cannot find the file specified. 
>       while executing
>   "spawn sftp user@host"

The only reason I see it's that sftp path should be specified somehow. I call this from a batch script and I've also tried changing the directory to sftp location before calling the script but the error is still the same.

Answer (score 2):

By far the most likely cause of the issue here is that the `sftp` program is not in a directory that is on your `PATH`. The concept is *almost* the same across platforms, but with some minor niggles.

### Working with the Unix `PATH`

Check to see if `sftp` is available in a `PATH`-known directory by typing:

```
which sftp
```

At your shell prompt. It should respond with the location of the `sftp` program, but if it isn't found then you get no response at all. If it isn't found, you'll need to find it yourself and add its location (strictly, the directory that contains the program) to the `PATH`. Find the program with something like:

```
locate sftp
```

Or (very slow!):

```
find / -name sftp -print
```

To append a directory to the `PATH`, do this in your shell:

```
PATH=$PATH:/the/dir/to/append
```

You can add a directory within the Expect script too (as long as it is before the `spawn`, of course!):

```
append env(PATH) : /the/dir/to/append
```

### Working with the Windows `PATH`

On Windows, use Windows Search (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> IIRC) and look for a file called `sftp.exe` (there's also a command line search tool, but I forget how to use it).

With the Windows PATH, a *little* more care is required:

```
append env(PATH) ";" {C:\the\dir\to\append}

# Or this...
append env(PATH) ";" [file nativename C:/the/dir/to/append]
```

Which is to say, the Windows `PATH` uses a different separator character (because `:` is used for separating drive names from directory parts) and the native name of the directory must be used, rather than the somewhat-more-convenient forward-slash variation (the backslashes interact with Tcl's syntax, hence the `{`braces`}`). Forward-slashes can be used provided you use `file nativename` to convert before appending, as in my second version.

### Some Tcl Techniques that can Help

You can use the Tcl command `auto_execok` to find out whether a program is on your `PATH` or not. For example:

```
puts [auto_execok sftp]
```

However, for some commands (notably `start` on Windows) you get a more complex response; the command really exists as part of the code that supports interactive Tcl usage, describing how to run some external program which can sometimes be a lot more complex than it appears to be at first glance. Still, it approximates to a cross-platform version of `which` as listed in the beginning of this answer...

Tcl 8.6 provides `$tcl_platform(pathSeparator)` variable as a way to get the `PATH` element separator character (a `:` or `;`, depending on platform). Probably doesn't help you though, as 8.6 hasn't yet been distributed as widely as previous versions.

Comment: I'm launching the tcl that tries to establish the sftp connection from a Windows batch command not from a linux script.

Comment: @user Ah! An important detail! The problem is still the PATH but the way you set it up and find programs is a bit different.